# QuickFix C++ how do I turn on SSL?

Tags: c++, networking, ssl, quickfix

I have an application using the java QuickFix library. I am trying to port it to C++. The problem is that the java version of the library seems to send the data over an SSL connection, while the C++ library sends the data unencrypted. In java, SSL is enabled internally in the library when I pass the config file to the library. The exact same file is passed to C++, but SSL is not turned on in the second case.

Please help me, how can I use QuickFix with SSL in C++?

Config file (sorry for the ?? too much sensitive information):

```
[default]
# QuickFixJ specific parameters (please do not modify)
FileStorePath=logs/session/
MessageProcessingDelay=6000

# Default parameter settings for your client (modify/add as needed), to be applied to all sessions.
ConnectionType=initiator
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=5
BeginString=FIX.4.4

SocketConnectHost=???.???.???.???
SocketConnectPort=??????
TargetCompID=??????
Username=??????
Password=??????
UseDataDictionary=N

#The following three lines are needed for Apache Mina SSL support only.
SocketUseSSL=Y
SocketKeyStore=config/ssl/ApacheMina/keystore.jks
SocketKeyStorePassword=?????????

#Declare and configure quote and trade sessions
#  beginning with a '[session]' designator for each session.
[session]
SenderCompID=????????
Account=???????????

[session]
SenderCompID=???????
Account=??????
```

Comment: Please could you post your config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the config file.
I have never used then switch `SocketUseSSL=Y`

Instead, in our production environment, in order to encrypt data over SSL we are using a free software: [sTunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html)

It's quite straightforward to install and config, and run over many different platforms.

Hope this can help.

Comment: I found out that SSL is not supported in the C++ version of the library, it's only available in the java version. I have successfully used the ssl proxy you suggested, and got a valid connection. Thank you :)

Comment: Can you tell me how did you configure this proxy in order to be able to connect to fx server witj SocketUseSsl ? I have the same problem but with quickfix/n

Comment: @TomAsh, please follow this link: https://www.stunnel.org/examples.html

Comment: @stexcec anywhere I can find more support on this with you or related? I don't seem to be able to success with stunnel and the c++ version. Although I specify the client port to forward communication to the FIX server, when I have stunnel on quickfix chooses another port to make the connection. If I don't have stunnel on, I see that the forwarding goes from the specified host/port in the config SocketConnectSourcePort and SocketConnectHost.

Answer (score 0):

quick fix has added ssl support in the recent c++ version

Comment: Has it been added for the C++ version? I didn't think it had...I'm still trying to establish connection via sTunnel.