# How to configure encryption standard in Quickfixn

Tags: c#, quickfix, quickfixn

How I would configure encryption standard for FIX connection in [Quickfixn](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/configuration.html).
I can see that for example for [Quickfixj](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.5.0/usage/configuration.html) there is a dedicated setting - `CipherSuites`, which

> Controls which particular SSL cipher suites are enabled for secure
>   connection

So in FIX config file I can have the following and have encryption standard applied:

```
SocketConnectHost=***IP host***
SocketConnectPort=***Port***
SocketUseSSL=Y
**CipherSuites=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA**
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1.1
SocketKeyStore=*** path to certificate ***
SocketKeyStorePassword=****
```

Now I need something similar for quickfixn, but it seems [SSL configuration](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/configuration.html#ssl) doesn't offer similar setting.

So how could I configure FIX connection to use a given encryption standard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360257/quickfix-c-how-do-i-turn-on-ssl

Comment: @stexcec thanks. I'm using C#, so SSL is enabled in [quickfixn](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/configuration.html#ssl) & I would try to avoid using any 3rd party tool if possible. Also I couldn't find anywhere in the config documentation on how would one configure desired encryption standard. Could you please help to find relevant pages of documentation (if you know ofc) ?

Comment: Try https://www.stunnel.org/examples.html